# TYPO3 - f:link.typolink with additionalAttributes and a condition?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-11.x

I am looking for a solution, how to include a query in additionalAttributes?

**Static:**

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{field.referenceLink}" title="{field.referenceTitel} - {field.referenceText}" additionalAttributes="{rel:'nofollow'}">
    Link
</f:link.typolink>
```

**condition:**

```
<f:variable name="nofollow"><f:if condition="{field.referenceLinkNofollow}"><f:then>{rel:'nofollow'}</f:then><f:else>{rel:'dofollow'}</f:else></f:if></f:variable>
```

**next Test:**

```
<f:section name="nofollow">
    <f:spaceless><f:if condition="{field.referenceLinkNofollow}"><f:then>{rel:'nofollow'}</f:then><f:else>{rel:'dofollow'}</f:else></f:if></f:spaceless>
</f:section>
```

**Dont Work like this:**

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{field.referenceLink}" title="{field.referenceTitel} - {field.referenceText}" additionalAttributes="{nofollow}">
    Link
</f:link.typolink>
```

**Error:**
*The argument "additionalAttributes" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\TypolinkViewHelper".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```html
<f:variable name="nofollow" value="{f:if(condition: '{data.no_follow}', then: 'nofollow', else: '')}" />
<f:link.typolink parameter="https://example.com" title="Title" additionalAttributes="{rel: '{nofollow}'}">
  Link
<f:link.typolink>
```

Let's assume that the variable `{data.no_follow}` represents the setting that backend users can change in the page properties ("Follow this page").

The first line sets the variable `nofollow` in the Fluid template to either the value `'nofollow'` or to `''` (*empty*), depending on the page property setting. I have used the inline notation of the *If*-ViewHelper to achieve this. The variable `{nofollow}` is then used in the *LinkTypolink*-ViewHelper as the value for the `rel=` attribute under `additionalAttributes`.

As empty values are dropped, the `rel=` attribute is only shown if it has value.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work if {field.referenceLink} and {field.referenceLinkNofollow} contains needed data.

```html
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{field.referenceLink}"
                     additionalAttributes="{f:if(condition: '{field.referenceLinkNofollow}', then: '{rel:'nofollow'}')}"
    >Linktext</f:link.typolink>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it works!

```
<f:variable name="nofollow" value="{f:if(condition: '{field.referenceLinkNofollow}', then: 'nofollow', else: '')}" />
```

**fluid:**

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{field.referenceLink}" title="{field.referenceTitel}" additionalAttributes="{rel: '{nofollow}'}">
```